# How to properly handle SequelizeConnectionError in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Below code  check coming connection authenticated or not

```
    ..............
    ..............
        sequelize
            .authenticate()
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
            })
            .catch(err => {

                console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
            });
....................
.....................
```

above connection process only display the "error" in **command prompt** not response the user. How to response the client(connection error) ?

Comment: That depends on what you are using to send to the client.  Node.js has a bunch of modules that can be used to send data to the client.

Comment: give some example

Comment: mani, if you found the answer useful, you should accept it as the answer or upvote it or both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is most popular or to best to learn, the expressjs website [hello world example](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) is about responding to a "/" path 'get' http request.

In your web app example code and using express.js, you might be checking sequelize for a database connection on each request, in which case you would do something like:

```
app.get('/', function(res, req) {
    sequelize
        .authenticate()
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
            //and do something like
            //send data to the client
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
            //
            res.send('Unable to connect to the database.');
        });
});
```

This express.js [documentation about basic routing](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html) might also be useful.